# Não aparece todos os tipos de dados do SQLite Studio

Tags: c#, sqlite-studio

está limitando as opções de tipos de dados disponíveis. Como pode ser alterado o tipo de dado de uma coluna específica no meu banco de dados SQLite usando o SQLite Studio?

[image: Foto com o erro!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O SQLite possui apenas os tipos de dados exibidos no SQLite Studio, BLOB, INTEGER, NUMERIC, REAL e TEXT.
Qualquer outro tipo, é apenas uma abstração desses tipos, por exemplo, BOOLEAN ou DATE são do tipo NUMERIC.

Veja mais sobre esse assunto na documentação do SQLite:
https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html